# Не розмовні синоніми до слова "мжичка"

Tags: синоніми

> [Мжичка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50951&page=1617) Дуже дрібні краплі води, які насичують повітря; дрібний,
>   густий дощ, сніг з дощем; мряка (у 1 знач.).

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BC%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)

> Мряка, мрячка розм., сльота розм., мжа діал.

Зокрема слово "мжа" в [СУМ -11](http://sum.in.ua/s/mzha) має позначку діал., а в [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50948&page=1617) позначки діал. вже немає.

Можливо є ще якісь не розмовні синоніми?

Comment: А чим не влаштовують формалізми, які використовуються у прогнозах погоди? На кшталт *«мінлива хмарність з проясненнями, подекуди дощ і туман, <s>вітер південно-східний, поривчастий</s>»*. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не розумію чому вам не підійшов варіант "мряка"? Він є в [СУМі](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5541/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) і біля нього немає позначок "діал." чи "розмов.", а значення у нього:

> Густий дрібний дощ, краплини якого немов перебувають у завислому
>   стані.

Біля слова "[сльота](http://sum.in.ua/s/sljota)" в СУМі також немає жодних позначок:

> Невпинний дощ, **мряка** або мокрий сніг.