# Переклад з російської "масляница"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

[- Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0*&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> Ма́сляница – ма́сниця, ма́сляна (-ної), ма́сляниця; ум. ма́сничка.

В СУМ-11 є слова "масниця" та "масничка"

> [Масниця](http://sum.in.ua/s/masnycja)  і, жін., церк. Давньослов'янське свято проводів зими,
>   пристосоване християнською церквою до тижня перед великим постом і
>   пов'язане зі звичаєм веселитися та готувати певні страви (млинці,
>   вареники з сиром і т. ін.).    [Масничка](http://sum.in.ua/s/masnychka) и, жін., церк. Пестл. до
>   масниця.

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F) окрім наведених вище варіантів, також присутне слово "масляна", якого немає в СУМ-11

> Масниця (церковне свято проводів зими), масляна, масляниця *розм.*,
>   масничка *пестл.*

Але більшість варіантів пошуку в Google подає саме слово "масляна" [1](https://24tv.ua/lifestyle/koli_maslyana_v_ukrayini_data_ta_traditsiyi_maslyanoyi_shho_ne_mozhna_robiti_n916719), [2](https://vv-hotel.com/ua/131/%D0%97%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B0), [3](https://tsn.ua/groshi/v-ukrayini-rozpochinayetsya-maslyana-skilki-koshtuvatimut-mlinci-ta-yak-obrati-pravilni-dlya-nih-produkti-1306455.html)

Чи є нормативним використання слова "масляна" для перекладу слова "масляница"? Чи варто надати перевагу використанню лише слів, які є в СУМ-11?

Answer (score 3):

Слово "[Масляна](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50013&page=1579)" з'явилося в СУМ-20, є там і "[Масниця](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50023&page=1579)", і "[Масляниця](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50017&page=1579)" (примітка "рідко"), і "[Масничка](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50025&page=1579)".

Так як всі ці слова є в офіційному джерелі, ви можете використовувати їх (хоч, бажано уникати слова "Масляниця") для перекладу слова "Масляница".